Upgrading Google Cloud Functions to New Runtime Using Batch Processing
I'm looking for a way to upgrade all of my Google Cloud Functions to a new runtime in one go. Currently, I have multiple Cloud Functions running in different runtimes, and I want to streamline the process of upgrading them to a newer runtime version.
Current Setup:

I have several Google Cloud Functions deployed in various runtimes, such as Node.js 12, Node.js 14, and Node.js 18.
These functions are critical to my application and are deployed across different projects and regions within Google Cloud Platform (GCP).

Goal:

Upgrade all existing Cloud Functions to a new runtime, such as Node.js 20  to leverage the latest features and optimizations.

My expectation is to migrate all cloud functions to a new runtime at a single time, like a batch process.
